# Search pattern for an if statement that isn't followed by curly brace on the next line

Tags: search, regular-expression

How would I formulate a search pattern for matching `if` statements that don't have an opening curly brace on the next line?  I assume it requires the use of something like `[^{]` or `\@!`, but I'm having trouble getting things to work correctly.

I'd like to match:

```
    if(some_condition)
        return;
```

but not:

```
    if(some_condition)
    {
        return;
    }
```

The `if` and `{` may be indented one or more levels and I think trying to account for the indentation is what's causing my problems.

My first attempt was to use this pattern:

```
if(.*\n\s*[^{]
```

This works if things aren't indented, but once they are it matches any `if` statement regardless of whether the first non-white space character on the next line is a `{`.

Comment: Of course: When indended, the last whitespace before the `{` will be matched by the `[^{]`, while the `\s*` eats one whitespace less. To avoid this, include the whitespace (and TAB, if needed) in that exclusion list: `[^ {]`

Answer (score 1):

Of course just before clicking the submit button, I thought of a way to do it:

`^\(\s*\)\zsif(.*\ze\n\1[^{]`

This works by capturing any white space before the `if` and searching for the same amount of white space at the start of the next line (using `\1`).  Note that this assumes that the white space before the `{` exactly matches the white space before the `if`.

The `\zs` and `\ze` just limit the highlighting to the actual `if` line.

Comment: In case you ever try to do this in a different regex language. You are looking _lookaround assertions_. More than likely a _negative lookahead assertion_. Many language do not provide `\zs` and `\ze` style zero-width assertions. Perl does have a zero-width assertion, `\K`, which is similar to Vim's `\ze`.

Comment: This will fail for either wrong indentions or mixed tab/whitespace indentions.

Comment: That's a good point.  I will clarify that my solution makes a number of assumptions.  Fortunately, they are assumptions that are valid for the code I'm currently dealing with.